Motor peak and continuous torque calculation
Given these motor characteristics for a BLDC motor ( maximum speed = 2000 RPM), what is the achievable continuous and peak torque with 24V input at very low RPMs (<50 RPM)?

To first order, your continuous torque figures are limited by I2R heating in and dissipation from the windings. The peak figure may be limited by strength of some kind, whether pulling the windings out, demagnetising the magnets, saturating the magnetic path, or by adiabatic heating in the windings. As the peak is specified for 1 second, that sounds like an adiabatic heating limit,
These limits are pretty much the same whether the motor is running at full speed, or is nearly stationary.
There will be some second order effects. Continuous cooling will be more efficient at high speed due to churning the air inside the motor, so heating could be worse at low speeds, reducing the permitted continuous current and so torque. Mechanical losses will be lower however, so more of the generated torque will be available at the shaft. You could run a test, while measuring the winding temperature.
Adiabatic heating will not be affected by motor speed, just take the peak figure as is.

Does this mean the continuous and peak torque can not be higher than the given values at 2000 RPM even at much lower RPMs with 24v?

@Raj That's what my answer means. If contoinuous cooling by churning the air in the motor is a significant factor, then low speed torque will be lower. The motor windings get hot from the passage of current, no matter how fast the rotor is spinning. Now at low speed, your power supply will be more lightly loaded, because it acts like a buck converter, the ESC will run the motor at a higher current than it draws from the supply.

It depends if the motor has a built-on a cooling fan. Given the Max continuous phase current 4.45A at max. speed, this parameter is somehow related to the motor speed. At first glance I would say, because it has a cooling fan, since we don't know what type of motor is. But, I guess your motor is a kind of RC or drone BLDC, so the continuous current is somewhere very near declared 4.45A. However this is not a fixed parameter, it matters the air temperature and flow around it. At lower speed the viscous rotor's drag of the fresh air will be lower, but also the iron losses due to eddy currents are smaller. So, as long the windings settle to a steady temperature which is lower than max. allowed, the continuous current is appropriate.
EDIT:
In my opinion the declared continuous current is a very good starting point. The peak current shall not be exceeded, because it can cause magnet tear off and demagnetization of the rotor. Also the ratio peak VS. continuous is approx 5.7 times. Designing a driver that can handle almost six times the rated current doesn't seem economically justified. Various industrial servo drives have this limit set to 250-300%. Therefore a driver with a current limit at 15A somehow fulfils the requirements.
To be continued...maybe

Thanks. It is for a gimbal. And there is no fan for cooling.
